# Label Setbounds Delay in seconds

Tags: java, swing, delay, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

So, I'm trying to make a racing program. In this case, I want the car to slow down until its speed is 0 as the user released the W key instead of a full stop.

Here's the code:

```
JLabel carImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("carimage.jpg"));
int carAcceleration = 100;
int carPositionX = 0, carPositionY = 100;
// assume it is already add in the container

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
    handleKeyReleased(key);
}

int slowdown = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer(1000,this); // 1000ms for test
public void handleKeyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
    if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        slowdown=1;
        timer.start();
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
    if(slowdown == 1) {
        while(carAcceleration> 0) {
            carAcceleration--;
            carPositionX += carAcceleration;
            carImage.setBounds(carPositionX, carPositionY, 177,95);
            timer.restart();
        }
    }
    timer.stop();
    slowdown = 0;
}
```

But then, when I release the W key. It waits for a full second and suddenly teleports 100px to the right and stops .

I also tried using Thread.sleep(1000); but same thing happens.

```
JLabel carImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("carimage.jpg"));
int carAcceleration = 100;
int carPositionX = 0, carPositionY = 100;
// assume it is already add in the container

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
    handleKeyReleased(key);
}

public void handleKeyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
    if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        while(carAcceleration> 0) {
            carAcceleration--;
            carPositionX += carAcceleration;
            carImage.setBounds(carPositionX, carPositionY, 177,95);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to execute like this.

```
carAcceleration | carPositionX  | Output    
----------------------------------------------------------------------
100             | 100           | carImage.setBounds(100,100,177,95);
                |               | PAUSES FOR SECONDS 
99              | 199           | carImage.setBounds(199,100,177,95);
                |               | PAUSES FOR SECONDS
98              | 297           | carImage.setBounds(297,100,177,95);
                |               | PAUSES FOR SECONDS
... and so on
```

Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: Why do you restart and then stop your timer?

Comment: quite logical and proper timing from whatever stopped by Thread.sleep(int)

Comment: I really don't know how to use it. I just googled them.

Comment: here are a few code examples using name Car, invoked by KeyListener, better (good concept and proper workaround for KeyEvents in Swing) examples which uses KeyBindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233735/230513) uses a damped spring model to mimic such deceleration. A `javax.swing.Timer` is used to pace the animation.

[image]

Comment: The only thing helped me about the example you gave was the structure of the timer and stuffs inside the actionPerformed of the timer. It was very helpful and now my car deccelerates slowly. Thank you!

Comment: @JuvarAbrera: Glad it helped; even though you didn't use the model cited, it might guide you in encapsulating your own model.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `carPositionX+=carAcceleration` try `carPositionY+=carAccleration`. This should make the car to move in the y axis of the coordinate system of the window.

Comment: Fail. You didn't get my question. Thanks though.