# How do i make an image move instead of jumping

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent

I want an image to move towards the mouse when the mouse moves towards it, and that image should move with the same speed the mouse is moving with, and when the mouse moves away from the image, the image moves in the opposite direction with the same mouse speed until the image reaches its origin point. And as for the neighbouring images they should do the same thing but with half the speed. Any idea how to do so ? i tried doing it but the images jump instead of moving.

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).

Comment: @trashgod tried it and didnt work, because "linex" and "liney" are fixed values with a certain direction.

Comment: *"because "linex" and "liney" are fixed values with a certain direction."* That does not make much sense to me. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of code with an attempt at using `Timer`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson if "linex" and "liney" increase for example, x/y = 0 then 1 then 2 then 3 and so on till10 then using a timer would generate an animation, but if x and y are  equal to 10 from the start then using a timer wont do anything.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Done

Comment: Create your `Timer` _outside_ `paintComponent()`, and `start()` it when everything's set up, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233735/230513).

Comment: @trashgod created it outside and started it and still same result

Comment: @Sherif: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: @trashgod the code above is the MCVE, i posted it yesterday

Comment: Your `ActionListener` is `null`, so your `Timer` will do nothing.

Comment: @trashgod implemented action listener and changed timer, still same result

Comment: An empty method will also do nothing.

Comment: @trashgod placed it in paintcomponent didnt work, put it in mouse moved didnt work, the problem i think has nothing to do with the timer, its with the values used to draw the rectangle. i dont know how to change them properly

Comment: @Sherif: Your requirement is sufficiently complex to warrant a separate model, a shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233735/230513).